# How to filter a liste of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in JS/Jquery, and I am trying to code an input zone that allows to show only items that contain letters entered by user in the input. I already did the following example, but the list in this case is static, and I'm trying to create a function where the list is variable.

https://jsfiddle.net/M33D/ffudxhqv/

This is what I did to resolve this problem, but it doesnt work. And I don't know exactly what to do

https://jsfiddle.net/M33D/ae2wLnfp/

I tried this function (autocomplete) of jQuery and it always doesn't work:

```
function filtrerAptitudes() {
    var listeDesAptitudes = jQuery('#conteneurAptitudes input');
    var nbrItem = listeDesAptitudes.length;
    var availableTags = []; 
    for(var i=0; i<nbrItem; i++) 
        availableTags.add(listeDesAptitudes[i].name);    
    $( "#conteneurAptitudes" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
};
```

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: I suggest leaving only essential information and code. Your post is pretty lengthy, and chances are most people won't read the whole thing.

Comment: @GMchris Thank you, I removed code snippets and I put JSFiddle links instead, I hope it's more clear now